# How to set up Fargate Service Auto Scaling with Step Scaling Policy in Pulumi?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, pulumi, aws-auto-scaling, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm trying to autoscale Fargate Service in AWS ECS based on CloudWatch Alarm (Namespace - AWS/SQS, Metric name - ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible). I managed to do that in the AWS Console but not via code (in Pulumi).

My suggestion for code is below:

```
const vpc = new awsx.ec2.Vpc("vpc", {
  subnets: [{ type: "public" }],
});

const my_cluster = new awsx.ecs.Cluster("my-cluster", { vpc });

const task = new awsx.ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(...)

const my_fargateService = new awsx.ecs.FargateService(
  "my-fargateService",
  {
    cluster: my_cluster,
    taskDefinition: task,
    desiredCount: 0,
  }
);

const sqs_queue = new aws.sqs.Queue(
  "fargateServiceQueque"
);
```

```
const autoscaling_Policy1 = new aws.autoscaling.Policy("autoscaling_Policy1", {
  policyType: "StepScaling",
  adjustmentType: "ExactCapacity",
  stepAdjustments: [{
    metricIntervalUpperBound: 1,
    scalingAdjustment: 0
  }],
  // I think problem here
  autoscalingGroupName: autoScalingGroupFromFargateService.name // ???
});
```

```
const sqs_less_than_1 = new aws.cloudwatch.MetricAlarm("sqs_less_than_1_message_visible", {
  comparisonOperator: "LessThanThreshold",
  evaluationPeriods: "2",
  metricName: "approximateNumberOfMessagesVisible",
  namespace: "AWS/SQS",
  period: "120",
  statistic: "Maximum",
  threshold: "1",
  dimensions: {
      QueueName: sqs_queue.name,
  },
  alarmDescription: "This metric monitors number of messages in sqs queue",
  alarmActions: [] // I think it should be -> [autoscaling_Policy1.arn],
});
```

The problem - I don't know how to retrieve auto-scaling group ("autoScalingGroupFromFargateService.name") from my_fargateService.

In AWS Console I do that as shown on images below:
[image]
[image]

And I'm getting this result:
[image]

Comment: I think Fargate doesn't have a feature to trigger the scaling according to the SQS queue message. I can only see the option with CPU and Memory metrics in both scaling (Target tracking and Step Scaling). If you have figure out a way please let me know as well.
Thanks

Comment: I was able to scale down and up based on the number of messages in SQS. The question was about that - I was not able to write all my code in Pulumi and some configuration was done manually in the console.

Comment: Cool, To get the SQS based scaling you set the Alarm first from the Cloudwatch then used the same existing in the scaling, is that right?

Comment: Excuse me for the late reply. Yes, I created - two metric alarms and used them to create autoscaling for service in ECS. One metric was used to scale down to 0 Fargate task and another to scale up to 2 Fargate tasks. I used the "Step scaling" type of dynamic scaling.

Answer (score 0):

To set up autoscaling for ECS Fargate you can use Pulumi `aws.appautoscaling`([docs](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/aws/api-docs/appautoscaling/target/#ecs-service-autoscaling)).